# Tangent space to the moduli space of abelian varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Letting $\mathcal{A}_g$ be the moduli space of principally polarized abelian varieties. I saw without reference that the tangent space of $\mathcal{A}_g$ at a point $t$ could be canonically identified with $S^2 H^0(\Omega^1_{A_t})^*$.

Could someone please explain where this identification comes from, or for some references to better understand what is going on here.

Comment: This follows from deformation theory, see e.g., Sections 2.3 and 2.4 of the article "Finite group schemes, local moduli of abelian varieties, ..." by Oort. The article does not talk about the moduli space of abelian varieties, to see the relation you need to note that the completion of the local ring at $t$ is isomorphic to the ring representing the local deformation problem considered by Oort. (Also, note that the statement you have written is not quite correct, it has to be interpreted stack-theoretically, or you have to work with the moduli space of ppavs with level structure.)

Comment: You might find Beauville's Varie'te's de Prym et Jacobiennes Interme'diaires helpful, chapter VII. http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=ASENS_1977_4_10_3_309_0